# Design Circuit ASK Modulation on DSRC (5.8 Ghz Freq)

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf, vhf

I want to do Ask modulation on DSRC. RF frequency is 5.8Ghz. I think, Op amp's seem's to work for me. But high frequency op amps are very expensive. Do you have any idea for me, could you give me circuit idea for  ASK modulation on DSRC? I new to RF circuit design . Thanks for help.

Comment: How would an op-amp help you even if the carrier is 1 MHz?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.